# Preloading files into memory for third party process

Tags: windows, memory, file-io

Basically I have some sort of third party software running on Windows 7 which does not take full advantage of installed RAM and keeps reading data from disk. As the whole content fits into memory, still leaving plenty to operate, the idea here is to pre-read all content with a self-written program to prime filesystem cache and preferably lock it into physical memory. Using a ramdisk would be too cumbersome.

Also, reading the content should occur in background while already running the third party software.

Some keywords come to mind:

- memory mapping.
- files larger than 4 GB.

What (free) programming language would you recommend for this task? Any idea on how to lock the mapped file into physical memory?

Comment: once it's read it from disk it will stay it the cache. Are you sure you have identified the problem correctly?

Comment: I fear the OS or any background task will slowly clear the page cache afterwards. A dirty solution would be to re-read the data periodically, which can be accomplished by a simple script (.bat or .vbs). A clean solution would be to tell the OS "page cache this and keep it cached unless I say otherwise", and I suspect there is some way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since about every language deeper than scripting had mmap support, I went with Python for a first proof-of-concept. It worked out very well. Can easily keep a 12 GB dataset consisting of tens of thousands of files in pagecache, increasing performance of the original app.